# How to remove BackButtonAction event listener?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have added event listener for back button with registerBackButtonAction, how can I remove that on exit from the page?

I tried offHardwareBackButton, but it doesn't remove listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`registerBackButtonAction` function return a function that, when called, will deregister this backButtonAction. You could do like this:

```
var deregister;
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
    deregister = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (e) {
        //suit yourself
    });
});

$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function () {
    deregister(); //remove listener
});
```